# Textbook suggestion-Vector Analysis

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, book-recommendation

I took a course in vector analysis this year. It was a two fold course. The first part covered linear algebra and basic euclidean geometry. The second took to more advanced areas such as differential geometry, and the integration theorems. We used vector analysis by Schaum(author: Murray Speigel). I was wondering if there are more books on the subject? Please make sure you state the things covered in the textbooks you mention.

Comment: What is your background in single-variable calculus, or in mathematical analysis? Mainly, I'd like to know if you've studied those subjects in a way that emphasized proofs and theory.

Comment: @ user204305 : Yes, I have. I have done advanced mathematical analysis, which is a course we take in my university. The course took a deviation to an introduction in functional analysis. You see the problem I have is that I understand the concepts behind vector analysis, but I cannot seem to apply it when presented with a real situation(in particular I am working on water etching). I want to improve my problem solving, although the textbook mentioned has many solved problems, it does not offer insight. Or maybe I was blind for it.

Comment: You could try Chapter 7 of Arnold's *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* for an intuitive explanation of differential forms. At a lower level, you could try Volume 2 of *Calculus* by Apostol. For a fuller theoretical treatment, you can look at *Advanced Calculus* by Loomis, or *Mathematical Analysis II* by Zorich.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schaum's Outline Vector Analysis by Murray Spiegel is useful for those who would devote themselves to advanced topics, where the vector analysis is just the beginning. Schaum's Outline Vector Analysis by Murray Spiegel is, I believe, not only covers the topic vector analysis, but also other interesting topics like Gauss' and Coulomb's Law, which can be explained by vector analysis. I suppose you are an engineering student, so you don't have to learn the intricacies of vector analysis. I would recommend the book Calculus with Analytic Geometry by Thurman S. Peterson (ISBN 97185-5804-9). It has a chapter that is devoted to vector analysis and its succeeding chapters covers other topics which is the logical consequence of learning vector analysis (example: divergence, curl, line and surface integrals).

It's a good book. Happy looking! Cheers!:-)

The book looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm3zN.jpg)

Note: That's not me. I'm uploading better picture for you.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend "Vector Calculus" by Michael Corral, which you can either download for free from here: https://www.mecmath.net/ or get a printed b/w copy from lulu here: https://www.lulu.com/de/de/shop/michael-corral/vector-calculus/paperback/product-7wd428.html?page=1&pageSize=4.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).